# How to redirect the output of a FTP recursive listing to a local file with Windows 7 FTP client?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ftp

When using the DOS command FTP in Windows 7, I can use this FTP command to list recursively all files of the remote directory:

```
ftp> ls -R
```

I cannot get the output of ls -R to a local file, FTP keeps complaining about the syntax:

```
ftp> ls -R . save.txt
usage: ls remote-directory local-file
```

Can someone explain why, and how to get the result I wanted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as far as i know once you are in the interactive ftp shell the output can't be captured.

but you can either pipe commands to the ftp command 
or specify a file with the commands (required if you need multiple commands, like specifying username/password)

then you redirect the std out to a file.

like this:

```
echo ls -R | ftp yourHostname > save.txt
```

or you place all your commands (lets say mycommands.txt) in a text file and call it with

```
ftp -s:mycommands.txt > save.txt
```

mycommmands.txt could look like this

```
user yourName yourPassword
open yourHostname
cd someDirectory
ls -R
```

(i couldn't test the second example right now, so let me know if it doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, there is an authentication error (using anonymous and email). However, against logic, this ftp command works "ls -R save.txt"

Comment: while the command above is correct, some FTP server-side implementation removed support for `ls -R`, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2007929

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using simple ftp via command line, 
Use dir command with -Rl option to search recursively and copy it to a file and then search the file using grep, find or whatever way is supported on your OS.

```
ftp> dir -Rl education.txt
output to local-file: education.txt? y
227 Entering Passive Mode (9,62,119,15,138,239)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
226 Transfer complete
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ftp> dir * Sample.txt
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could use improvement by explaining *why/how* your solution fixes/addresses the OPs question. Also, from the looks of your command this won't create a recursive directory output as required by the OP.