# WinSCP find command too slow

Tags: winscp

So I am trying to search a directory with more than thousands of files in it, and it is very slow. Is there a way to search an FTP directory with more than 10k files in it within reasonable time (there is a main directory with thousands of folders in it, and each of those folders can have 10 or so files)? I do not have SSH access.

Comment: Doesn't the FTP have a published directory index? Downloading that, and then grepping through it is WAY faster than a LIVE search.  
 **An Index** = Text file containing filename and path of the entire server's content recursively. It is often compressed and located in server root or /pub/

Comment: If you have only SFTP access, an option might be to parallelize the search with multiple connections using some script.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about the good old fashioned FTP (and not SFTP)?

If that is the case and you don't have any other form of access then your only option is to download a full directory listing, save it as a local text file and search that (using grep or any tool of your choice). Of-course you will need to update the directory listing file every once in a while.

Here's how to download the directory listing:
[How to redirect the output of a FTP recursive listing to a local file with Windows 7 FTP client?](https://superuser.com/questions/790253/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-ftp-recursive-listing-to-a-local-file-with-windo)

By the way, if it's a shared web hosting service that doesn't provide SSH you can work around that issue by uploading a small CGI/PHP/Node script that runs the find command and prints the result (just make sure to properly secure it).